# Regex - Match Pattern with list of values

Tags: java, regex

I have a input like `google.com` and a list of values like

```
 1. *.com
 2. *go*.com
 3. *abc.com
 4. *le.com
 5. *.*
```

I need to write a pattern in java which should return all the matches except `*abc.com`. I have tried a few but nothing worked as expected. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("*.com");
        values.add("*go*.com");
        values.add("*abc.com");
        values.add("*le.com");
        values.add("*.*");
        String stringToMatch = "google.com";
        for (String pattern : values) {
            String regex = Pattern.quote(pattern).replace("*", ".*");
            System.out.println(stringToMatch.matches(regex));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
false
false
```

I have tried this but the pattern doesn't match.

Comment: Post your attempts please.

Comment: I can able to do only the reverse match. ie., input with *.com matches google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your code:

```
String regex = Pattern.quote(pattern).replace("*", ".*");
```

To this:

```
String regex = pattern.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transform the given patterns into regexes, and then use normal regex functions like String.matches():

```
for (String pattern : patterns) {
    final String regex = pattern.replaceAll("[\\.\\[\\](){}?+|\\\\]", "\\\\$0").replace("*", ".*");
    System.out.println(stringToMatch.matches(regex));
}
```

edit: Apparently `Pattern.quote()` just adds `\Q...\E` around the string. Edited to use manual quoting.

edit 2: Another possibility is:

```
final String regex = Pattern.quote(pattern).replace("*", "\\E.*\\Q");
```

Comment: what does \\E.*\\Q do? The issue is fixed now.

Comment: @RajaAsthana \Q starts escaping all characters in the pattern and \E ends this. Thus `\E.*\Q` inserts the (unescaped) regex `.*` into the escaped sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881055/1225328) (read the comments of the question, very instructive), here is a wildcardsToRegex method:

```java
public static String wildcardsToRegex(String wildcards) {

    String regex = wildcards;

    // .matches() auto-anchors, so add [*] (i.e. "containing")
    regex = "*" + regex + "*";
    // replace any pair of backslashes by [*]
    regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)+(?!\\\\)", "*");
    // minimize unescaped redundant wildcards
    regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)[?]*[*][*?]+", "*");
    // escape unescaped regexps special chars, but [\], [?] and [*]
    regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)([|\\[\\]{}(),.^$+-])", "\\\\$1");
    // replace unescaped [?] by [.]
    regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)[?]", ".");
    // replace unescaped [*] by [.*]
    regex = regex.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)[*]", ".*");
    // return whether data matches regex or not

    return regex;

}
```

Then, within your loop, use:

```java
for (String pattern : values) {
    System.out.println(stringToMatch.matches(wildcardsToRegex(pattern)));
}
```

Comment: How different is this from Njol answer. Could you please explain.

Comment: @RajaAsthana This *literally* transforms a wildcards string to a regex, while @Njol's solution uses the `\Q...\E` escape sequence (more info about this syntax [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), section "Special Characters", last §). Both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            values.add("*.com");
            values.add("*go*.com");
            values.add("*abc.com");
            values.add("*le.com");
            values.add("*.*");
            String stringToMatch = "google.com";
            for (String pattern : values) {
                String regex = pattern.replaceAll("[.]", "\\.").replaceAll("[*]", "\\.\\*");
                System.out.println(stringToMatch.matches(regex));
            }
```